# creating a daemon process in linux

Tags: c, linux, process, timer, daemon

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

        /* Our process ID and Session ID */
        pid_t pid, sid;

        /* Fork off the parent process */
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {             //child process
                CreateSocket();    //this function will recieve the data from the client
        }
        else
        {
         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);   //exit the parent process
        }

        /* Change the file mode mask */
        umask(0);

        /* Open any logs here */        

        /* Create a new SID for the child process */
        sid = setsid();
        if (sid < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* Change the current working directory */
        if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);

        /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */

        /* The Big Loop */
        while (1) {
           /* Do some task here ... */

           Timer();   // this will create a timer and call the task for every 2ms, 10ms
        }
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My task is to recieve the data from the client via the socket and run the timer in the background. So I created a parent process and child process and later the daemon process to run in the background. I called the function called CreateSocket(); within the child process to recieve the data from the client in the child process and I am not doing anything in parent process (just I am exiting). Later calling the daemon to run my timer task in the background

my question : If i do as above then my timer task will be keep on running in the background and create socket will be keep on recieving the data from the client

Comment: If i do as above then my timer task will be keep on running in the background and create socket will be keep on recieving the data from the client.

Comment: And what did you expect to happen different from that?

Comment: I want my timer to run in the background

Comment: That's what you said it does. So what is the issue?

Comment: I dont have the client to send data!! so i am asking you guys - if I do like above will it work ?? my socket program and timer is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to daemonize some process is to use the [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) library function (internally based upon `fork` and `setsid`...) near the beginning of your program (e.g. before creating any thread).

Comment: if I used just daemon and call my timer within that then will my timer run in the background ?? could you give me a small example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you app is one of these types:

```
{
  ".sh": "bash",
  ".py": "python",
  ".rb": "ruby",
  ".coffee" : "coffee",
  ".php": "php",
  ".pl" : "perl",
  ".js" : "node"
}
```

you want to use npm's pm2 package.

It will daemonise your app just by running pm2 start.

Moreover, whilst your app typically runs on 1 core, with pm2 you can run your app on *all* cores very easily and it will load balance between the cores. If this sounds too exotic for you then it's easy not to load balance too!

This is what you do:

```
npm install -g pm2

pm2 start app.js -i 0 --name "api" # load balance app on all cores

pm2 start app.js --name "api" # run on 1 core, like apps typically do
```

then:

```
pm2 startup (creates a pm2 systemd or equivalent service)

pm2 save (remembers the apps pm2 is running and starts them on reboot)
```

Done!

Comment: Using `npm` assumes people are willing to use `node.js` to manage this task.  That is quite a leap to make in a question tagged with C as the only language.